# setAttribute not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, setattribute

I have a problem with setAttribute() . I have searched the internet and this website but they did not solved my problem . I want to change the width and height of a picture with javascript but it does not work . please help me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Width Height Changer</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function chang(){
            var wid = document.getElementById('width').value;
            var hei = document.getElementById('height').value;
            var set = document.getElementById('pic');
            if(Number(wid) && Number(hei)){
                set.setAttribute("style","width : wid");
                set.setAttribute("style","height : hei");
            }else{
                alert('Error');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="width" placeholder="Enter Width"/>
    <input type="text" id="height" placeholder="Enter Height"/>
    <button onclick="chang()">OK</button><br/>
    <img src="back4.jpg" id="pic" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables are treated as strings since they are quoted - change to:

```
if(Number(wid) && Number(hei)){
    set.setAttribute("style","width :" + wid + "px");
    set.setAttribute("style","height :" + hei + "px");
} else {
```

Comment: thanks for your answers . my problem fixed but I prefer to use setAttribute because for my learning it is better . thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

better to use:

```
set.style.width = wid +"px";
set.style.height =hei+"px";
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdragon/jqTLZ/)

```
function chang(){
        var wid = document.getElementById('width').value;
        var hei = document.getElementById('height').value;
        var set = document.getElementById('pic');
        if(Number(wid) && Number(hei)){
            set.style.width = wid +"px";
            set.style.height =hei+"px";
        }else{
            alert('Error');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
set.style.width = wid + "px";
set.style.height = hei + "px";
```

or

```
set.style.setAttribute("width", wid + "px");
set.style.setAttribute("height",hei + "px");
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommend a few changes as well to improve readability.  Using an id="width" and "height" is confusing since width/height are also JS/html keywords.  Also some additional error checking never hurts:

```
function chang(){
        var wid = document.getElementById('inputWidth').value;
        var hei = document.getElementById('inputHeight').value;
        var set = document.getElementById('pic');
        if(Number(wid) && Number(hei) && set && set.style){
           set.style.setAttribute("width", wid + "px");
           set.style.setAttribute("height",hei + "px");
        }else{
            alert('Error');
        }
    }
```